# Can't access password query from mysql in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, bash, git

I'm using an **ubuntu git bash**, and I can get the password query to show. Here is the screenshot of what happens:

[image]

Can somebody help me on how to show the password query I have set a password for the user `'kristoffer'@'localhost'`, however it does not show.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple (as the error message also says): there is no field named `password` in the [mysql.user table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-tables.html) (see `Table 6.3 user and db Table Columns` within the linked page). The password field is called `authentication_string`, that's what you need to use in your query.